# Knights fighting a steam locomotive they believe is a dragon

Tags: story-identification

I read a story many years ago about 2 knights in the English moors waiting for a dragon that has killed previous knights. The dragon turned out to be a steam locomotive. Does anyone know the title and/or author?

Answer (score 17):

This is [The Dragon, by Ray Bradbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragon_(short_story)).

> The story concerns two knights who have a mission to slay a dragon. They describe the dragon as huge, fire-breathing, and horrific, having only one eye. They charge the dragon but fail, presumably dying in the attempt. The "dragon" is then revealed to be a steam train, and its single eye is the train's headlight. The operators discuss the event but go away without attempting to find the knights.

Comment: Kind of makes you wonder why nobody from the knight's home town ever followed the rails to see where they led... Or noticed the crews who laid the rails in the first place.  But then, it's Bradbury. One does not read Bradbury for scientific realism.

Comment: @SolomonSlow As far as I remember, Bradbury uses here (and in other stories) the sort of merged realities, which come into existence only for a brief time, usually during some solitary experience by a person. It is a common enough trope in many mystery novels since at least 19th century or earlier. Neither steam locomotive nor rails exist in the same reality as the knights' world -- except for a brief moment in a limited area during some (misty and solitary) nights.